# Run two python script automatically on Headless raspberry pi project

Tags: raspbian, python, headless

I'm doing a project where raspberry pi runs headless. I have written two python programs, one for swiching off the raspberry pi via gpio push button and the other is a opencv-python program.
I need to run both the programs at startup and both are endless scripts . The first program shutdown rpi safely when the button is pressed and other does image processing. How to run both automatically when rpi is started ?

Comment: Not sure what to do, both are endless scripts. will putting python p1.py & python p2.py &  in /etc/rc.local work ?

Comment: I'd either do that or add it as a reboot cron job.  Whatever you try make sure you give the full path to the script, e.g. not p2.py but /home/pi/p2.py.

Comment: If you put them in `/etc/rc.local` and they are persistent, make sure you fork them, e.g. `p1.py &`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either  `crontab -e`  and append  `@reboot path/to/script`  or navigate to `/etc/rc.local` and put it in there like this  `script.py &`.

Answer (score 3):

Look into using [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to manage your scripts.  It is available as a package for Raspbian.

Supervisor can restart the scripts if they crash and capture any the output and log it. It can also run the script as a non-privileged user if you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cron:

```
crontab -e
```

and append:

```
@reboot path/to/your/script
```

This approach doesn't restart your scripts if they exit with an error, though.